# Sum of two different condition in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this T-SQL query

```
SELECT 
    ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM 
    ProductStockIn 
WHERE  
    OrgName = @OrgName
    AND Statecode = 'ADD' OR Statecode = 'ORDER' 
    AND CreatedOn BETWEEN DATEADD(MS, 3, @LastGenerationDate) AND @GenerationDate 
GROUP BY 
    ProductId) stockin  ON p.ProductId = stockin.ProductId
```

I have this kind of table

```
|quantity | StateCode | CreatedOn |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|400      | ORDER     | <date>    |
|400      | ADD       | <date>    |
```

I want to sum all quantity where StateCode is equal to 'Order' And 'Add' but in my query it only select StateCode = ADD .. when i tried to Condition StateCode = 'ADD' AND StateCode = 'ORDER', nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM ProductStockIn 
WHERE  OrgName = @OrgName AND Statecode in( 'ADD','ORDER')
AND CreatedOn BETWEEN DATEADD(MS,3,@LastGenerationDate)
AND @GenerationDate 
GROUP BY ProductId
having count(distinct Statecode)=2
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it solved my problem , can I ask one more thing:
my CreatedOn Column has :
'2020-11-04 01:48:42.400'
'2020-11-04 01:41:03.203'
'2020-11-04 01:49:18.403'

I have this -LastGenerationDate equal to 2020-11-03 00:00:00.00
and -GenerationDate equal to '2020-11-04 00:00:00.00'

my query can't sellect those three rows of CreatedOn, unless I set my -GenerationOn equal to '2020-11-04 23:59:00.00'

Comment: so what do you want to do with the date and time? @MCMXCVIII

Comment: I want to select those three when GenerationOn is equal to '2020-11-04 00:00:00.00'. because this code is automatically run in midnight , so im assuming its 12:00AM or 00:00:000 Time ..

Comment: I get it now, I cant select that three rows because it is greater than 2020-11-04 2020 00:00:00 , thanks a lot